# Equivalent to 'WHEN OTHERS THEN' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In Oracle functions we can use Exception handling in the following way

```
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN

    // do some error handling

    RETURN NULL;

    (Then END for function end -- also function return value returned before the exception part)
```

Now to execute the same thing in sql server.. we have try and catch logic

How can I mention a condition that will work as 'WHEN OTHERS THEN' as in oracle in sql server.

In oracle 'WHEN OTHERS THEN' catches all other exceptions than the one's mentioned excplicitly

Is there a way to catch all exceptions in this way in sql server

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `TRY CATCH` as follows

```
BEGIN TRY  
   -- statements that may cause exceptions
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH  
   -- statements that handle exception
END CATCH
```

`Case Statement` and `IIF` should help

Comment: T-SQL doesn't support `Case` (`Switch`) statements, only `CASE` expressions, which aren't logical flow operators, and so are unlikely to help.

Comment: of course but they probably could help in these situation.